# Shader compile errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

I am trying to compile a "garbage" shader, feeding in some garbage code to WebGL (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yjGV5/) for a fiddle):

```
gl = $('canvas')[0].getContext('experimental-webgl');

source = 'garbage12398sv;aa[]|\[12';

shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
gl.compileShader(shader);

console.log(gl.getError() === gl.NO_ERROR);
```

Surprisingly, `gl.getError() === gl.NO_ERROR` is `true` despite asking WebGL to compile some garbage.

Why doesn't `getError` flag an error? How can I get error information regarding the compilation status of my shaders?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

gl.getError only returns errors for the OpenGL pipeline. A shader failing to compile does not cause an error in the pipeline. You can read about gl.getError [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml). You can query the status of shader like so:

```
var compiled = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
console.log('Shader compiled successfully: ' + compiled);
var compilationLog = gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader);
console.log('Shader compiler log: ' + compilationLog);
```

Similarly, shader program linking errors do not invalidate the OpenGL pipeline and can't be detected with gl.getError() you must call the object (shader, program, render buffer, etc) specific error query functions.

Comment: Just a quick reminder that this answer got a dead link! Please fix.

Comment: In my case i get true but still not passing ` if (gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) `